# How can I see to which records I am subscribed to unfollow them?

Tags: chatter, subscriber, follow

How can I see to which records I am subscribed to unfollow them on the standard Salesforce user interface?

When I try to follow some record I receive this error but I don't understand how can I unfollow or unsubscribe the records I currently follow since I don't know which records I am following.

> You are subscribed to the maximum number of records. Unsubscribe from
>   another record and try again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this discussion https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gjunAAA, 
you need to open "My profile" and click on following items.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to standard UI way to mass unsubscribe another user from the record the other user is following?

Comment: @Patlatus I think no, I can see that idea posted 8 years ago and still hasn't met review threshold.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000J61sAAC

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more recent development to help manage this. Salesforce Labs created a managed package to create unfollow rules for chatter: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IX0UEAW